# Where is the xUnit project type in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit, visual-studio-2022, xunit.net

I just installed Visual Studio 2022 but I cannot add a new xUnit project. When I go to the `File > New > Project...` screen, the only type of test project it offers me is MSTest:

[image]

I have added the following NuGet packages:

[image]

I have closed and reopened VS 2022, but it still won't give me the option of creating an xUnit project.

Is there anything else I need to configure or install to be able to add xUnit projects to my solution? (for reference, I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community version 17.2.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing some workloads from Visual Studio Installation. It appears here -

[image: Visual Studio 2022 XUnit Project Template]

Comment: Do you know which workload(s) I need to add during installation? When I looked at the various workloads that were available, it wasn't obvious which one(s) would bring in the testing frameworks.

Comment: Your suspicion was correct. I went back to the Visual Studio Installer and installed the "ASP.NET and web development" workload. After that, the xUnit project type showed up for me as an available option (like you show in your picture above). It's possible that installing other workloads would have had the same effect. (Originally I had only installed the "Visual Studio extension development" workload and I guess that wasn't enough).

Comment: @RSW Thanks for confirming. I dont have access to my machine right now and wont have it for next 12 hours so was bit difficult for me to get back to you on this.

Comment: I have no problem with the project template but I can no longer find the xUnit item templates. I used to have several xUnit templates I could add as classes, have they been removed?

Comment: @Zoey I had to install this VS2022 extension to get them to show up.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YowkoTsai.xunitnettestgenerator2022

Comment: @busbina I installed that extension and restarted visual studio but still not xUnit Test classes I can add. In previous versions of VS I would have a "Test" subfolder under C# Items and in there it would have MS Unit test items as well as xUnit.

Comment: @Zoey, I see what you are saying, there are no options from the "Add New Item/Class" Wizard. The only way I have been able to get the templated classes to be built is to use the "Create Unit Test" option from the function context menu, then select the XUnit.net 2.0 Test Framework

Comment: @busbina very strange. I know in previous versions of VS I could add xUnit templates and it would create a class with the xUnit references and a generic [Fact] like UnitTest1 or something. I can't remember which version that worked in, maybe VS2017 or 2019.